How to bundle MongoDB binary with Electron app
How can I bundle MongoDB binary with Electron.js, so that user can store data locally and not need to install MongoDB server on user local machine. I integrate the MongoDB binary with Electron app and it locally work fine but after build I got error during launching Electron app.
Here is the error:

Failed to start MongoDB:
Error: Command failed:
"/opt/MystroCommander/resources/app.asar/backend/MongoDB/bin/mongod"
--dbpath "/opt/MystroCommander/resources/app.asar/backend/MongoDB/data" --port
27017 /bin/sh: 1:
/opt/MystroCommander/resources/app.asar/backend/MongoDB/bin/mongod:
not found
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl
dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

I cross check the app.asar file and MongoDB is there having MongoDB.
I try locally it working fine but got error in build.

It could be easier to bundle SQLite, as this does not need an external process

"mongod: not found" is a pretty big clue. Can you open up the compressed build to see if that binary really is in there? What platform are you compiling for?

@NicoHaase is it fessible to bundle MongoDB with Electron.js?
